# Spresense SDK における 16kHzサンプリングでのデータ取り込みについて教えてください

Tags: spresense, audio

こちらのサイトを参考に、16kHzサンプリングでのPCMキャプチャをしようと試みています。
https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_developer_guide_ja.html#_audio_recorder_functions

そのために、以下の設定を行いました。

```
    
//マイク設定　　　　
AudioCommand command;
command.header.packet_length = LENGTH_INIT_MICFRONTEND;
command.header.command_code = AUDCMD_INIT_MICFRONTEND;
command.header.sub_code = 0x00;
command.init_micfrontend_param.ch_num = 4;
command.init_micfrontend_param.bit_length = 16;
command.init_micfrontend_param.samples = 768;
command.init_micfrontend_param.out_fs  = 16000;
command.init_micfrontend_param.preproc_type = AsMicFrontendPreProcSrc;
snprintf(command.init_micfrontend_param.preprocess_dsp_path, AS_PREPROCESS_FILE_PATH_LEN, "%s", "/mnt/sd0/BIN/SRC");
    
//録音設定　　　　
AudioCommand command;
command.header.packet_length = LENGTH_INIT_RECORDER;
command.header.command_code = AUDCMD_INITREC;
command.header.sub_code = 0x00;

command.recorder.init_param.sampling_rate = 16000;
command.recorder.init_param.channel_number = 4;
command.recorder.init_param.bit_length = 16;
command.recorder.init_param.codec_type = AS_CODECTYPE_LPCM;
command.recorder.init_param.computational_complexity = AS_INITREC_COMPLEXITY_0;
    
snprintf(command.recorder.init_param.dsp_path, AS_AUDIO_DSP_PATH_LEN, "%s", "/mnt/sd0/BIN");
```

ですが、取り込めるデータが期待した量の1/3ぐらいしかありません。

どこか他にケアすべき箇所がありましたら、恐れ入りますがご指摘をお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

自己解決しました。 どうやら、マイク設定と録音設定の両方で16kHz指定すると、今回のような動作になるようですね。音声ブロックのフローを見てまさかと思いましたが、どちらか片方だけにすると期待通りのデータが得られました。 SONYの中の人からの回答が得られなくて残念でしたが。

Answer (score 0):

取得したデータは所望のデータではないのでしょうか？
その際、どのようにおかしいのか？を記述すると何かヒントを得られやすいです。

・チャンネルのデータが正しくない。（チャンネルデータが混ざっているなど）
・所望の音より早送りのような音になっている。

など、データの状況で起こっていることが想像できます。

ちなみに、1/3となると、Spresenseは48kHzでのキャプチャを1/3して16kHzにするので、そのあたりの認識のずれがあるのかもしれませんね。

ご参考になれば。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。

具体的には、およそ１秒間のキャプチャを実行した結果得られるデータ量が、
48kHzのときは  380,928バイト (理論的には384,000バイト)
に対し、
16kHzのときは  41,336バイト (理論的には128,000バイト)
しか得られていないのです。

Comment: 録音された音声などはどう聞こえるのでしょうか？

Comment: 1kHzの正弦波を録音すると、3kHzの正弦波が記録されていました。

Comment: データ長ですが、10秒の録音で3.3秒しか記録されませんでした。データ量が1/3なので当然ですが。